# What’s the meaning of the nilpotency of Higgs fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

In Liu and Zhu’s [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06282), remark 1.10(i), the following result from the [article](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1992__75__5_0.pdf) of Simpson, Corollary 4.2 is cited:

> If $L$ is a Betti local system on a complex smooth projective variety that
> underlies a variation of Hodge structure, then the corresponding Higgs
> bundle $(M, \theta )$ under the (classical) Simpson correspondence is nilpotent.

However the original statement from Simpson’s article is

> The representations of $\pi_{1}(X)$ which come from complex variations of Hodge structure are exactly the semisimple ones which are fixed by the action of $\mathbb{C}^*$.

It confused me how we get Liu&Zhu’s statement from Simpson’s original form. Also, I’m not cleared about the definition of a *nilpotent Higgs field*, mainly confused in how they define the iteration of it. I guess it should be
$$\theta^n: E\otimes \Omega^{n-1} \rightarrow E\otimes \Omega^{1}\otimes \Omega^{n-1}, \theta\otimes Id $$
for Higgs field $\theta $ over holomorphic vector bundle $E$.